# Why is it that large linear SVM coefficients denote the most important features?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for an intuitive explanation, preferably geometric. Why is it that I sort the coefficients of my linear SVM I get the most indicative features as the ones with the large coefficients?

Suppose I have only 2 features X1 and X2. Their corresponding coefficients are simply the slope of the line separating the 2D space, right? Why is it that if the coefficient for X1 is 3 while the one for X2 is 1, it means that X1 is more indicative of the target class variable than X2?

Comment: This question will get better answers at Cross Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

My colleague Doron convinced me in the following explanation:

Suppose we are trying to classify documents to the "is_fashion" target variable - are they dealing with fashion or not? We have only 2 features `x` is TFIDF score of the word "dress", and `y` is the TFIDF score of the word "new", and each document can be represented as a point in this 2D space.

Suppose that the `y` feature isn't relevant at all to the target, while the `x` feature is a great predictor, so that every document with a `x` score of above 3 is dealing with fashion, and those with a score of below 3, does not deal with fashion. The SVM separating line would look like `1x + 0y -3 = 0`, or `x = 3`.

The classification of a new document  would be `1*x + y*0 - 3`, which is nothing but the projection (dot product) of the document on the perpendicular to the separating line. This example clearly shows how a feature with a 0 coefficient does not affect the classification.

Let's complicate a bit. What if the word "new" is a bit relevant to fashion, but not as relevant as "dress"? The separating line (black in the image) would now be `5*x + 1*y - 3 = 0`, or `y = -5x + 3`. The perpendicular (red in the image) would be `y = x/5 + 3`
[image: svm_plot]

Classification would now be a projection on the red line. The point <2,2> would get a classification score: `5*2 + 1*2 -3 = 9`. If our important feature `x` is subtracted 1, we would need to move 5 steps higher in the `y` dimension to get the same score, to the point <1,7> which would also get a score of `5*1 + 1*7 -3 = 9`.